# bottom navigation menu html/css

Tags: html, css, menu, bottomnavigationview

I want to make a website with a normal top menu on big screens and a bottom menu in small screens but I'm confused if I need to create two different menus.

For example:

```
<nav class="menu">
    <img src="logo.png" alt="logo">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>

<nav class="mobile-menu">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
        </li>
        <li>
            <i class="fas fa-settings"></i>
        </li>
        <li>
            <i class="fas fa-home"></i>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Or is there another way to do this?

I want a menu like this on big screens:

[image: menu on big screens]

And like this on small screens:

[image: menu on small scresns]

Answer (score 1):

You can use CSS @media queries to change the style of the menu based on screen size.

For example

```
.menu {
   position: fixed;
   top: 0;
   width: 100%;

   /* ... */
}

/* this will override the settings above when the screen size is smaller than 600px wide */
@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .menu {
    top: auto;
    bottom: 0;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to only use HTML and CSS you can use display none with [Media Querys](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/CSS/Media_queries) so it displays the correct nav on different sizes. If you know how to use JavaScript use can rewrite the content of the  with [.innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) and using JS media querys.

See this Bootstrap example. They are changing the class in the html as the screen is being resized. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/navbar/

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
            Dropdown
          </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><hr class="dropdown-divider"></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">Disabled</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <form class="d-flex">
        <input class="form-control me-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">Search</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```